# Custom environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is it possible to set a custom environment variable, which will be accessible from any other plugin, the same way as `$platform` and `$path` works?

There is a package [EnvironmentSettings](https://bitbucket.org/daniele-niero/environmentsettings/src) by Daniele Niero, but it seems my task is simpler and therefore there is a probablity that there is no need to dive deep into its code.

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you're trying to accomplish with these variables?

Comment: @OdatNurd I use custom directory instead of default `User` to store my preferences and keybindings files. Sometimes some of my custom plugins need to read/write these preferences. One day I may decide to change the name of this directory or put it inside some another one - and it will be some inconvenience to manually change all paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime, any plugin can modify the global process environment through `os.environ` from the Python run time. All plugin code runs under the same process, so once one plugin sets an environment variable, any other plugin could access it. I would imagine that this is how the package that you linked to in your question modifies the environment.

A simple example of this in action can be found in `Default/exec.py` which you can open by using `View Package File` from the command palette. In the `__init__` method of `AsyncProcess()` there is code that modifies the Sublime process environment if you pass the `path` argument in your `sublime-build` file.

A simple example that you can run from the Sublime console would be the following snippet. Once you execute that code, any plugin that you create can access `os.environ["MY_VARIABLE"]` to see the value.

```py
import os
os.environ["MY_VARIBLE"]="Some Value"
```

With that said, in Sublime `$platform` is not an environment variable, it's a special variable that Sublime knows how to expand itself which is divorced from the system environment outlined above.

A complete list of such variables can be viewed by executing the following code from the Sublime console:

```py
from pprint import pprint
pprint(window.extract_variables())
```

The list of variables you get and their content depends on application state (platform, whether there is currently a project open in the window, the current file, etc).

The names of the variables that this returns are hard coded in the Sublime core and can't be augmented, so if you wanted extra variables here you would need to communicate that to other plugins and they would have to be modified to know how to use them.

From the sounds of what you're trying to accomplish in the comments on your question, what you want might be a `sublime-settings` file that contains a setting that specifies the directory to use for file actions in your custom plugins. If they all load the settings file to get the path you can modify the location in the config and have it take effect immediately. Alternatively you could do something like a top level module variable in one plugin and `import` it into the others.